# How to change width of aLenghtMenu in dataTables?

Tags: datatable, datatables, bootstrap-4

How do I change width of this drop down menu, as you can see it's too small. When I select 10, it's not visible

[image: DataTable with smaller width of dropdown menu]

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution, had to change css like this

```
div.dataTables_wrapper div.dataTables_length select{
width:50px;
}
```